# Uninstalling unity results in booting to white screen

Tags: 10.10, unity

I installed unity from the software center then decided to eventually remove it.

Now my desktop boots to a while screen. I get the nvidia splash and then a white screen. I can see my mouse pointer and move it around and if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> plus arrow I can see the workspace switcher, but that's its.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> gives me a command prompt.

How do I recover my desktop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of playing around I found that I still had gnome-shell installed so I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
```

and then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity
```

This said that unity was not installed but that a bunch of packages where no longer required including ubuntu-netbook-unity-default-settings and suggested I call:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

this followed by:

```
sudo restart gdm
```

gave me a working desktop again.

Comment: I suppose that we'll have a lot of questions about Unity here on Askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I started Ubuntu 10.10 in safe desktop mode it worked well without smooth effects.Then i logged out and logged in in normal mode and it worked good like before. But it was bit slow
then i tried:
sudo apt-get autoremove unity

it said that unity is not installed but it removed unity libraries and related things. And so it worked.!